# Dynamic Small Airways Collapse - Understanding the physics of the pressure drop from alveolus to mouth in human lungs

Tags: fluid-dynamics, medical-physics

**EDIT:**
I think I have thought of a much better phrasing of my question using the middle diagram below.

a) If intrapleural pressure is >0 does airway collapse always occur?

b) In a hypothetical scenario where intrapleural pressure is say +5, alveolar is maybe +10, might some part of the airway only be +2 (5>Pairway>0) and consequently collapse occurs?

c) Most of all is there some physics principle that describes how pressure behaves along the length of the airway such that I might predict when collapse would occur in scenarios such as 'b'?

*Old question continued below...*

**Specific Question:**

I wish to understand how the pressure would change along the length of the respiratory tract during expiration.

If I could stick pressure sensors all along an idealised respiratory tract from the alveolus through the various conducting airways to the mouth/nose and out into the atmosphere what principle would guide my pressure findings?

**Application:**

In certain pathological circumstances during expiration the pressure at a point along the airways drops below the expiration-driving-pressure of the surrounding lung and the airway collapses causing airway obstruction.

I'm studying medicine and I wish to understand what laws or principles govern how the pressure changes along the airway from the alveolus (presumably at highest pressure?) to the mouth (presumably lowest at atmospheric pressure?).

Would pressure drop linearly along my theoretical pipe with high pressure "balloon" at one end and atmosphere at the other?

**Mechanics of breathing background
:**

- Chest wall (in contact with parietal pleura) has tendency to expand outwards
- Alveoli and lung parenchyma (in contact with visceral pleura) have tendency to collapse inwards
- Potential space between parietal and visceral pleura has relative negative pressure
- The pressure in this pleural space is termed Intrapleural pressure
- Transpulmonary pressure is the difference between this intrapleural pressure
- My second diagram shows how transpulmonary pressure drive respiration

[image: Intrapleural and Transpulmonary Pressures]
[image: Driving Pressure of Lung]

**My terrible diagram approximating what I think might be happening**

I just made up all the values in this diagram as an example of the principle I am trying to understand.

[image: Dynamic Small Airways Collapse Diagram]